# Validate array values with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How to check if some values inside an array are "unique" in some database table ?

If I have some array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => value0 [1] => value1  [2] => value2  [3] => value3  )
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
$this->validate($request,
 [        
    '*.selectedvalues'=>'unique:items,name',  
 ]
);
```

am I using it right !?

Comment: `array-unique`?

Comment: you "have some array like this" ... where, what is the inputs name?

Comment: @ppz .. what does `array-unique` refer to?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a description of a problem ... what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to guess you meant this:

```
'selectedvalues.*' => 'unique:....',
```

Assuming the input `selectedvalues` is the array with the items you want to check for uniqueness. [ for each `selectedvalue` element, run this rule against them ]

Comment: yes, this 'selectedvalues' is an array come form an input form , which i want to validate the values inside it if they are unique in the database.

Comment: then there you go :)

Comment: in what format or form should the array looks like so this rule will apply to it?

Comment: what "doesn't work" ... what are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening

Comment: well this array is stored in $request->selectedvalues and when I give this array some values which already are stored inside the database table "items" it will still go and doesn't  say " oh wait some of the array values are already stored in database"

Comment: ok I found out what I was doing wrong, I was trying to store the array inside selectedvalues by using $request->selectedvalues = $array inside the controller.. but this doesn't really change the $request "selectedvalues" parameter, I should have used it like: $request['selectedvalues '] = $array; and now the validation works.

Comment: yea trying to set a dynamic property will not actually set the source of the input ... glad you figured it out :)